# Android ACTION_UP doesn't work even though return true

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I tried to use MotionEvent in onTouch method but... it never works

I also searched on google and found that in onTouch method it needs to return true.

I did but still not works...

Any ideas?...

```
        imageViewCancel.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ACTION : " +  event.getAction());
            switch(event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION UP");
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION DOWN");
                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                            view);
                    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Here is my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#85d2ce">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewWakeUp"
        android:layout_width="140.5dp"
        android:layout_height="121.5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/messages"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewAlarmClock"
        android:layout_width="157.5dp"
        android:layout_height="153.5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_alarm"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAmPm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewRingingTime"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="44dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_cancelWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutLeftArrowWrapper"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.21">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLeftArrow"
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="24.5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSnooze"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.17"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_alarm_10min"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.22">

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.17"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_alarm_off"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutRightArrowWrapper"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.21">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewRightArrow"
            android:layout_width="47dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my Activity java code

```
public class AlarmAlertLvOneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "AlarmAlertLvOneActivity";

private Alarm alarm;

private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

private AlarmLogDataBaseManager alarmLogDataBaseManager;
private SnoozeDataBaseManager snoozeDataBaseManager;

private int time;
private long timeInMillis;

private AlarmAlert alarmAlert;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_alert_lv_one);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    alarm = bundle.getParcelable("Alarm");


    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("app_setting", MODE_PRIVATE);

    alarmLogDataBaseManager = new AlarmLogDataBaseManager(getApplicationContext(), null, null, -1);
    snoozeDataBaseManager = new SnoozeDataBaseManager(getApplicationContext(), null, null, -1);

    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("mode") != null && getIntent().getStringExtra("mode").equals("snooze")) {
        snoozeDataBaseManager.snoozeOff(getIntent().getLongExtra("snoozeId", 0));

        AppController.getInstance().setNotificationController(getApplicationContext());
        AppController.getInstance().getNotificationController().notifyNotificationChanged(NotificationController
                .NOTI_SNOOZE);

    }

    alarmAlert = new AlarmAlert(getApplicationContext(), alarm);

    time = 60 * Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) + 60 * 60 * Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar
            .HOUR_OF_DAY);
    timeInMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

    setArrowAnimation();
    initViews();
    initSoundAndVibrate();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

Animation fadeInOutAnimcation;

private void setArrowAnimation() {
    fadeInOutAnimcation = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeInOutAnimcation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    fadeInOutAnimcation.setDuration(1000);
    fadeInOutAnimcation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    fadeInOutAnimcation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
}


ImageView imageViewCancel, imageViewSnooze, imageViewRightArrow, imageViewLeftArrow;
LinearLayout linearLayoutRightArrowWrapper, linearLayoutLeftArrowWrapper;
TextView textViewRingingClock, textViewAmPm;

private void initViews() {

    setTextViewAmPm();
    setTextViewRingingClock();

    linearLayoutLeftArrowWrapper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutLeftArrowWrapper);
    linearLayoutLeftArrowWrapper.setAnimation(fadeInOutAnimcation);

    imageViewLeftArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewLeftArrow);

    imageViewSnooze = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewSnooze);
    imageViewSnooze.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    linearLayoutRightArrowWrapper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutRightArrowWrapper);
    linearLayoutRightArrowWrapper.setAnimation(fadeInOutAnimcation);

    imageViewRightArrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewRightArrow);
    imageViewRightArrow.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()){
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Arrow ACTION DROP");
                    finish();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    imageViewCancel = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewCancel);
    imageViewCancel.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d(TAG, "ACTION : " +  event.getAction());
            switch(event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION UP");
                    //view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION CANCEL");
                    //view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.d(TAG, "ACTION DOWN");
                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                            view);
                    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)
                        view.startDragAndDrop(data, shadowBuilder,view,0);
                    else
                        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}

private void setTextViewAmPm(){
    textViewAmPm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewAmPm);
    if ((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) > 12)
        textViewAmPm.setText("PM");
    else
        textViewAmPm.setText("AM");
}

private void setTextViewRingingClock(){
    textViewRingingClock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRingingTime);
    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("24Hour_OnOff", false)) {
        if ((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE)) < 10)
            textViewRingingClock.setText((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":" + "0" +
                    (Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
        else
            textViewRingingClock.setText((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":" + (Calendar
                    .getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
    } else {
        if ((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE)) < 10)
            textViewRingingClock.setText((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR)) + ":" + "0" + (Calendar
                    .getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
        else
            textViewRingingClock.setText((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR)) + ":" + (Calendar
                    .getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
    }
}

private void initSoundAndVibrate() {
    alarmAlert.initSoundAndVibrate(alarm.isVibrationIsOn(), alarm.getSoundUriInString());
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    alarmAlert.quitSonndAndVibrate();
    alarmLogDataBaseManager.saveLogData(
            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),
            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),
            Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            time,
            alarm.getTime(),
            (int) (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - timeInMillis) / 1000,
            true);

    Log.e("Elapsed", (Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - timeInMillis) / 1000 + "");

    AppController.getInstance().setNotificationController(getApplicationContext());
    AppController.getInstance().getNotificationController().notifyNotificationChanged(NotificationController
            .NOTI_ALARM);
    AppController.getInstance().getNotificationController().notifyNotificationChanged(NotificationController
            .NOTI_SNOOZE);
}
```

}

Comment: Please explain what exactly does not work. Do you get no on-screen reaction at all? Do the `Log` methods get called?

Comment: @Bryan When I drag imageViewCancel, ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_CANCEL are called step by step but not ACTION_UP. Also Log.d(TAG, "ACTION UP"); is not called

Comment: If `ACTION_CANCEL` is sent no other motion events will be sent to the `onTouch()` method. `ACTION_CANCEL` occurs when another view in your layout hierarchy [intercepts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) the motion events. This is why `ACTION_UP` is never being sent, but I am not sure why `ACTION_CANCEL` is sent in the first place. Post your layout xml so I can get a better sense of what might be causing this behavior.

Comment: @Bryan thanks for reply. I just added all my codes(java and xml). If other view intercepts the motion events, is it possible that setOnDragListener's DragEvent intercepts it?